# Convert field type from div to input on click

Tags: html, angularjs

I have a div that should be displayed as such, but when you click on the div, I need it to transform into an input field.

This is what I have before that div is clicked:

```
<div>This is the content.</div>
```

I wan this to become the following when it's clicked:

```
<input>This is the content.</input>
```

And to change back when the user clicks elsewhere.

Is such a thing possible with Angular? I looked into using ng-change as a HTML tag, however I couldn't seem to get it going.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
<div ng-click='toggleShowInput()' ng-hide='showInput' >This is the content.</div>
<input ng-show='showInput'>This is the content.</input>
```

and controller has function like

```
function cntrl($scope){

    $scope.showInput = false;
    $scope.toggleShowInput = function()
     {
         $scope.showInput = !$scope.showInput;
     }
}
```

Comment: you can check link https://plnkr.co/edit/8Ip1yQgCqBIne9IyUIDQ?p=preview

Comment: This is a very useful answer since it also taught be a better way of doing reverse assignments. I used to do if (true) { var = false; } else { var = true; } and your approach is so much nicer to read. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

If you use Angular, you should write both element and toggle one for the other when the user click :

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html ng-app>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div ng-show="!inputIsOn" ng-click="inputIsOn = true">Click here</div>
  <input ng-show="inputIsOn" type="text">
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Nope, but the good news is that you don't need that to happen!

In your controller:

```
$scope.showInput = false;
$scope.myContent = "This is the content";
```

Back in your HTML file:

```html
<div ng-hide="showInput">{{myContent}}</div>
<input ng-show="showInput" ng-model="myContent" type="text" />
<button ng-click="showInput = true" />
```

Now when the button is clicked, the input field will display, but the text will not.